# Is "Open Web API" the same thing as "Streaming API Events"?

Tags: visualforce, api

Is "Open Web API" the same thing as "Streaming API Events" ?

I am using "API Request" and I need to know that "API Request" is NOT "Open Web API" " and I need to know that "API Request" is NOT "Open Web API"

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard the term "Open Web API" in the context of Salesforce. Can you please provide some references for what you're talking about?

Answer (score 3):

As best I can tell from Google searches, an "Open Web API" is:

> one that is openly an[d] freely available for anyone to use. Open APIs make a lot of sense on the web, where an open web API can be used to let third party software developers integrate pieces of your web site into theirs. For example Yahoo’s open search APIs let you integrate Yahoo search into your own site. This also works for integrating maps or photos or lots of other things into your site. [[Source]](https://toni.org/2007/01/30/open-source-vs-open-apis/)

It seems more conceptual than something you could actually open up a port to and send data back and forth.

The [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm) on the other hand is a very concrete API that you can interact with from your programming language of choice.

To me, most of the [Salesforce APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_APIs) fall close to being Open Web Apis with the exception that you typically need to pay to use Salesforce services beyond a developer edition org. Other than that, they are freely available for you to integrate with.